# Thread safety issue while calling method in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, executorservice, callable

I have a library in which customer is passing a `DataRequest` object which has information containing userid and other fields. We use that `DataRequest` object to make an HTTP call to two different REST service and then make a `DataResponse` object and return it back to the customer. I am having a global level timeout in my library which is applied on both HTTP call and if the call gets timedout, then we just return back with timeout error message to customer while making `DataResponse` object.

Given a `DataRequest` object I will make HTTP call to a service which will give me back some stuff and then basis on that I will make List and then for each `DataRequest` object I will call `performDataRequest` method in parallel in same global timeout I have in `getSyncData` method and then make `List<DataResponse>` object and return the response.

Below is my `DataClient` class which customer will call by passing `DataRequest` object:

```
public class DataClient implements Client {

    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    private ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(15);

    @Override
    public List<DataResponse> getSyncData(DataRequest key) {
        List<DataResponse> response = new ArrayList<DataResponse>();
        Future<List<DataResponse>> responseFuture = null;

        try {
            responseFuture = getAsyncData(key);
            response = responseFuture.get(key.getTimeout(), key.getTimeoutUnit());
        } catch (TimeoutException ex) {
            response.add(new DataResponse(DataErrorEnum.CLIENT_TIMEOUT, DataStatusEnum.ERROR));
            responseFuture.cancel(true); // terminating the tasks that have got timed out
            // logging exception here               
        }

        return response;
    }   

    @Override
    public Future<List<DataResponse>> getAsyncData(DataRequest key) {
        DataFetcherTask task = new DataFetcherTask(key, restTemplate);
        Future<List<DataResponse>> future = service.submit(task);

        return future;
    }
}
```

Below is my `DataFetcherTask` class which does all the work:

```
public class DataFetcherTask implements Callable<List<DataResponse>> {

    private DataRequest key;
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    public DataFetcherTask(DataRequest key, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.key = key;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public List<DataResponse> call() throws Exception {
        List<DataRequest> keys = performKeyRequest();
        List<Future<DataResponse>> responseFutureList = new ArrayList<Future<DataResponse>>();

        for (final DataRequest key : keys) {
            responseFutureList.add(executorService.submit(new Callable<DataResponse>() {
                @Override
                public DataResponse call() throws Exception {
                    return performDataRequest(key);
                }
            }));
        }

        List<DataResponse> responseList = new ArrayList<DataResponse>();
        for (Future<DataResponse> future : responseFutureList) {
            responseList.add(future.get());
        }

        return responseList;
    }

    private List<DataRequest> performKeyRequest() {
        List<DataRequest> keys = new ArrayList<>();
        // use key object which is passed in contructor to make HTTP call to another service
        // and then make List of DataRequest object and return keys.
        // max size of keys list will be three.
        return keys;
    }       

    private DataResponse performDataRequest(DataRequest key) {
        Mappings mappings = ShardMapping.getMappings(key.getType());
        List<String> hostnames = mappings.getAllHostnames(key);

        for (String hostname : hostnames) {
            if (DataUtils.isEmpty(hostname) || ShardMapping.isBlockHost(hostname)) {
                continue;
            }
            try {
                String url = generateUrl(hostname);
                URI uri = URI.create(url);
                ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, key.getEntity(), String.class);

                ShardMapping.unblockHost(hostname);
                if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) {
                    return new DataResponse(response.getBody(), DataErrorEnum.NO_CONTENT,
                            DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS);
                } else {
                    return new DataResponse(response.getBody(), DataErrorEnum.OK, DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS);
                }
            } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException ex) {
                HttpStatusCodeException httpException = ex;
                DataErrorEnum error = DataErrorEnum.getErrorEnumByException(httpException);
                String errorMessage = httpException.getResponseBodyAsString();
                return new DataResponse(errorMessage, error, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
                // logging exception here                   
            } catch (RestClientException ex) {
                ShardMapping.blockHost(hostname);
                // logging exception here                                       
            }
        }

        return new DataResponse(DataErrorEnum.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);       
    }
}
```

**Probem Statement:-**

- Is my code thread safe with the way I am calling `performDataRequest` method in parallel from call method?
- And secondly it feels very weird to have `call` method inside another `call` to do this job? And for this I am having two executors as well, one inside `DataClient` class with 15 threads and other in `DataFetcherTask` class with 10 threads. Not sure whether this is the right way to do? Is there any better way?

Answer (score 1):

> Is my code thread safe with the way I am calling performDataRequest
>   method in parallel from call method?

Mostly, but not completely. Is it possible for one thread to modify `ShardMapping` while another thread is calling `ShardMapping.getMapping()`?  For example, does `ShardMapping.unblockHost()` modify `ShardMapping`? If so, you're screwed if two threads are trying to call `ShardMapping.unblockHost()` at the same time. Does that make sense?

The fix is to make `PerformDataRequest()` *only* do the HTTP request, and not do the `ShardMapping` logic. Something like this:

```
private DataResponse performDataRequest(URI uri, DataRequest key) {
       try {
           ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, key.getEntity(), String.class);
           if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT) {
                return new DataResponse(response.getBody(), DataErrorEnum.NO_CONTENT,
                        DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS);
            } else {
                return new DataResponse(response.getBody(), DataErrorEnum.OK, DataStatusEnum.SUCCESS);
            }
        } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException ex) {
            HttpStatusCodeException httpException = ex;
            DataErrorEnum error = DataErrorEnum.getErrorEnumByException(httpException);
            String errorMessage = httpException.getResponseBodyAsString();
            return new DataResponse(errorMessage, error, DataStatusEnum.ERROR);
            // logging exception here
         } catch (RestClientException ex) {
            return null;
            // logging exception here                                       
         }  
}
```

Then move the `ShardMapping` code outside of the future, in the `for (final DataRequest key : keys) {` loops.

> And secondly it feels very weird to have call method inside another
>   call to do this job? And for this I am having two executors as well,
>   one inside DataClient class with 15 threads and other in
>   DataFetcherTask class with 10 threads. Not sure whether this is the
>   right way to do? Is there any better way?

That is a bit silly, and it's not the best way. Right now, your setup looks like this:

```
                          +----------------- performDataRequest()
                          |
         max 3 sec        |       
getAsyncData --- DataFetcherTask ----------- performDataRequest()
                          |
                          |
                          +----------------- performDataRequest()
```

Instead, why don't you put the 3 second timeout on the `performDataRequest()` future, then just call `DataFetcherTask.call()` normally?

```
                                  max 3 sec
                          +----------------- performDataRequest()
                          |
                          |       max 3 sec
                 DataFetcherTask ----------- performDataRequest()
                          |
                          |       max 3 sec
                          +----------------- performDataRequest()
```